# Creating removable comment command without extra space

Tags: spacing, macros, comments, notes

I'm trying to create a command we can use for comments in our document.  During development, we want the comments to appear; for production, we want them to disappear.  This is a common enough problem with many solutions.

I'm having an issue with LaTeX's tokenizer, though; if the command is surrounded by spaces, two spaces are emitted.  I understand why that's happening, but none of the workarounds that I can find are any good for me.  Here's a representative example.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\newif\ifnotes
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\ifnotes{#1}\fi}
\notesfalse
\newcommand{\nonotes}{\notesfalse}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

Testing \note{X} testing testing.

\end{document}
```

Because `\notesfalse` has been invoked, the note should not (and does not) appear.  But the spaces to the left and right of the command *do* appear, which is a problem for me.

I could modify the command to eat all of the spaces after it, but this isn't really the correct behavior either; if the command *only* has spaces following (as in `the\note{...} text`), there should still be an emitted space.  While I know that one can use things like `\unskip` to delete preceding space, I'm at a loss to *detect* the preceding (and following) space so I can make an intelligent decision about whether it should stick around.

Does anyone have any suggestions for accomplishing this task?

Comment: you could redefine `\note` to be `{\unskip\ \ignorespaces}` but you might also need to test whether you're in horizontal mode.  (i don't remember whether the space-eating commands complain if the command is launched in vertical mode, and don't have time to experiment.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\newif\ifnotes
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\@bsphack\ifnotes{#1}\fi\@esphack}
\makeatother
\notesfalse
\newcommand{\nonotes}{\notesfalse}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

Testing \note{X} testing testing.

Testing\note{X} testing testing.

Testing \note{X}testing testing.

Testing\note{X}testing testing.

\notestrue

Testing \note{X} testing testing.

Testing\note{X} testing testing.

Testing \note{X}testing testing.

Testing\note{X}testing testing.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not only *a* solution, *the* solution provided by LaTeX.

Comment: @Manuel yes you're right.

Comment: Mmm… in fact `\@bsphack\@esphack` only should be in case `\notesfalse`.

Comment: @Manuel I am not sure I undestand why?

Comment: I agree with @Manuel on this one; there's a subtlety that requires the hack to be avoided when notes are enabled.  The reason is actually in your output: on the fifth line, the X should have spaces both before and after it.

That said, `\newcommand{\note}[1]{\ifnotes{#1}\else\@bsphack\@esphack\fi}` is *exactly* what I wanted!  Thanks!

Comment: @tvynr By the way, the braces around `#1` are not required, you should remove them unless you actually want them there `\newcommand*\note[1]{\ifnotes#1\else\@bsphack\@esphack\fi}`.

Comment: I should probably mention here that http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294693/multiple-space-hacks-generate-more-space includes a fix for the case in which two notes are adjacent to each other.